# Why does a TextBox not inherit the background colour?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here is a fully reproducible example:

```
<Window x:Class="DemoWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Name="GridMain">

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <StackPanel>
            <Label>First Content</Label>
            <TextBox>First Edit</TextBox>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label>Second Content</Label>
                <TextBox>Second Edit</TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The output of this is as follows:
[image: Window and Label with red background, but TextBox with white background.]

What I find confusing is that the [`TextBox` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox?view=net-5.0) has a `BackgroundProperty` which inherits from `Control` - no different than the `Label`. However, as can be seen the `TextBox`es do not have their background colour changed. Although the `Grid` does not have a `Control.Background` property, but has a `Panel.Background` property, yet it still has its background property set, even though the property being set is `Control.Background`.

Comment: The `TextBox` and the `Label` do indeed share the same `Background` property but they set it to different *values* by default. Just set the `Background` to `Transparent` if you don't like the default: `<TextBox Background="Transparent">First Edit</TextBox>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I find confusing is that the TextBox class has a BackgroundProperty which inherits from Control - no different than the Label. However, as can be seen the TextBoxes do not have their background colour changed.

Each control has a default [style and control template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/fundamentals/styles-templates-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0). They define the required parts of a control, its apprearance and its visual states. The `Background` is one of the properties that *may or may not* be defined, depending on the control. For the controls that you use, the backgrounds are defined like this:

- `Label`: `Transparent`
- `TextBox`: [`SystemColors.WindowBrushKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemcolors?view=net-5.0)
- `Grid`: None, default value.
- `StackPanel`: None, default value.

Consequently, the `Label` appears to be red, but is not. It is the `StackPanel` or `Grid` background that you see through its `Transparent` background. For the `TextBox`, the background does not change because of [dependency property setting precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#dependency-property-setting-precedence-list). The background value of the default *implicit* style of `TextBox` just has a higher precedence than your local style setter.

What to do now? Assign the background with a higher precedence, e.g.:

- Add it as a local value.
- Define a style and assign it directly to the `Style` property of `TextBox`.
- Define an implicit style for `TextBox`

  ```
  <Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
     <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Red"/>
  </Style>
  ```

> Although the Grid does not have a `Control.Background` property, but has a `Panel.Background` property, yet it still has its background property set, even though the property being set is `Control.Background`.

That is another implementation detail in WPF. As you can see in the [reference source for `Panel`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/Panel.cs,144), it defines the `Background` property, but when you look at the [reference source for `Control`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/Control.cs,119), you can see that **it does not define** a `Background` property itself, but adds itself as the owner of the property defined by `Panel`. From the [documentation of `AddOwner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.addowner?view=net-5.0):

> Typically, AddOwner is used to add dependency properties to classes that do not already expose that dependency property through managed class inheritance (class inheritance would cause the wrapper properties to be inherited by the derived class, and thus would provide general members-table access to the dependency property already). AddOwner enables the property system to recognize a dependency property on a type that did not register that dependency property initially.

In other words, the properties work as if they were inherited and the XAML processor is smart enough to recognize that the `Control.Background` and `Panel.Background` properties are essentially the same.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

Because it's not transparent, it has a color by default:

[image]

A text box is an input field so it should be easy to spot.

On the other hand, `Label` is transparent for **convenience/design**:

[image]

Assuming it had a default color (in this case, blue) it wouldn't be very convenient, right ?

[image]

We get to the point, labels should melt into background, while fields such as textboxes should be easily distinguishable by nature.

Answer (score 0):

Used **BaseOn** property For inherited

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DefaultStyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
            <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
        <Style  TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultStyle}"/>
        <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultStyle}"/>
        
    </Grid.Resources>


    <StackPanel>
        <Label>First Content</Label>
        <TextBox>First Edit</TextBox>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label>Second Content</Label>
            <TextBox>Second Edit</TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```